# Why Isnt My Array (Based On Time) Being Ascendency Sorted?

Tags: javascript, sorting, datetime, time, momentjs

I have this script here

```
let myVar = [{time: "3:00 pm", name: "Landon"},{time: "5:20 pm", name: "Amanda"},{time: "4:00 pm", name: "Kid"}]
const sortedArray  = myVar.sort((a,b) => new moment(a.time).format('hh:mm a') - new moment(b.time).format('hh:mm a'))
console.log(sortedArray)
```

The idea is that we sort the array by time. But its not working and Im not sure why.

Every google search leads me to answers like this: https://gist.github.com/onildoaguiar/6cf7dbf9e0f0b8684eb5b0977b40c5ad

But it does not work for me.

Comment: Try some debugging and check the warning that Moment is throwing you - those strings are invalid for dates

Answer (score 0):

Your code passes a format at the wrong moment. You need to specify the *input* format, not the *output* format.

So change to:

```js
let myVar = [{time: "3:00 pm", name: "Landon"},{time: "5:20 pm", name: "Amanda"},{time: "4:00 pm", name: "Kid"}]
const sortedArray  = myVar.sort((a,b) => new moment(a.time, 'hh:mm a') - new moment(b.time, 'hh:mm a'))
console.log(sortedArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: `the wrong moment` ... I see what you did there